# How to test functions using Pester (how to loop Context block)

Tags: powershell, function, testing, pester

Hi i am trying to test my functions in the module but I need to know the right syntax. Here is what i have so far.

```sh
#array of functions 
     
$functions=('Get-Values',
            'Set-Value',
            'Publish-Value')

foreach($function in $functions) 
  
Context "Test Function $functions"{
    It "$function should exist"{
        "$function" | Should Exist 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First this is invalid PowerShell syntax. The `foreach` loop body must always be enclosed in curly braces: `foreach($function in $functions) { <# loop body #> }`.

Apart from that, Pester doesn't support regular loops around the structural elements like `Describe`, `Context` and `It`. Since **Pester 5** you can use [data driven tests](https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/usage/data-driven-tests) instead:

```sh
Describe 'My Functions' {

    Context 'Test Function <name>' -ForEach @(
        @{ Name = 'Get-Values' }
        @{ Name = 'Set-Value' }
        @{ Name = 'Publish-Value' }
    ) {
        It 'should exist'  {
            Get-Command $name -EA SilentlyContinue | Should -Not -BeNullOrEmpty
        }
    }
}
```

Also, `Should -Exist` tests for existence of filesystem items only. To test existence of command, use `Get-Command`. The parameter `-EA` (`-ErrorAction`) `SilentlyContinue` suppresses error output from `Get-Command`, when command isn't found. In this case `Get-Command` outputs `$null`, so with `| Should -Not -BeNullOrEmpty` we check if command exists.

Comment: Error Occurred: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ForEach'

Comment: @Stacker Have you installed latest version of Pester? PowerShell comes with very old version of Pester. Install new version: https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/introduction/installation

Comment: I am using the Pester 3, do you have the Syntax for it?